cut/extend edges to edge of other mesh
I would like to cut the edge at the edge of the cyrcle.

I would apreciate some help on that!
Thanks
Update: target is to create a plane in the form of the circle + the other form. If this could be achieved in a differnet way - hints would be apreciated!



hello do you mean that you want to create a vertex at the intersection of your 2 meshes?

yes and no! the two horizontal edges are too long and reach into the circle. So I would like to cut them exactly at the edge of the circle. If - what I don't know - a vertex is the solution - then yes. But I think a vertex at the edge of the circly can only be a helper - and is probably not the solution.

Boolean mods might not work totally with a non-manifold mesh like this but I think Boolean difference would probably work exactly like what you're aiming for.

@Jakemoyo question is: howto

I found a different way, I imported an image of that form and worked forward to get the vertices of the shape and improved that.
I am sure there are more easy ways to do this, but at least I got the result I needed.
